# What's causing local variable reference error?

Tags: python

- ALSO: CAN SOMEONE tell me why it's not picking up 'website'?

  ---

I'm trying to figure out what's causing this error:

line 60:
What's causing this error??? Only arising on the first line:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'name' referenced before assignment
```

Code:

```
import re
import json
import jsonpickle
from nameparser import HumanName
from pprint import pprint
import csv
import json
import jsonpickle
from nameparser import HumanName
from pprint import pprint
from string import punctuation, whitespace

def parse_ieca_gc(s):  

    ########################## HANDLE NAME ELEMENT ###############################

    degrees = ['M.A.T.','Ph.D.','MA','J.D.','Ed.M.', 'M.A.', 'M.B.A.', 'Ed.S.', 'M.Div.', 'M.Ed.', 'RN', 'B.S.Ed.', 'M.D.']
    degrees_list = []

    # check whether the name string has an area / has a comma
    if ',' in s['name']:

        # separate area of practice from name and degree and bind this to var 'area'
        split_area_nmdeg = s['name'].split(',')
        area = split_area_nmdeg.pop()
        print 'split area nmdeg'
        print area
        print split_area_nmdeg

        # Split the name and deg by spaces. If there's a deg, it will match with one of elements and will be stored deg list. The deg is removed name_deg list and all that's left is the name.
        split_name_deg = re.split('\s',split_area_nmdeg[0])
        for word in split_name_deg:
            for deg in degrees:
                if deg == word:
                    degrees_list.append(split_name_deg.pop())
                    name = ' '.join(split_name_deg)

    # if the name string does not contain a comma, just parse as normal string
    else:
        area = []
        split_name_deg = re.split('\s',s['name'])
        for word in split_name_deg:
            for deg in degrees:
                if deg == word:
                    degrees_list.append(split_name_deg.pop())
                    name = ' '.join(split_name_deg)

    # area of practice
    category = area

    # name
    name = HumanName(name)
    first_name = name.first
    middle_name = name.middle
    last_name = name.last
    title = name.title
    full_name = dict(first_name=first_name, middle_name=middle_name, last_name=last_name, title=title)    

    # degrees
    degrees = degrees_list

    # website
    website = s.get('website','')

gc_ieca = dict( 

name = name, 
website = website,
degrees = degrees,
),

myjson = [] # myjson = list of dictionaries where each dictionary
with(open("ieca_first_col_fake_text.txt", "rU")) as f:
     sheet = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter="\t")
     for row in sheet:
         myjson.append(row)

for i in range(4):
    s = myjson[i]
    a = parse_ieca_gc(s)
    pprint(a)
```

example data (made up data):

```
name    phone   email   website 
Diane Grant Albrecht M.S.           
"Lannister G. Cersei M.A.T., CEP"   111-222-3333    cersei@got.com  www.got.com
Argle D. Bargle Ed.M.           
Sam D. Man Ed.M.    000-000-1111    dman123@gmail.com   www.daManWithThePlan.com
D G Bamf M.S.           
Amy Tramy Lamy Ph.D.
```

[Download ex data](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fxHVcFrg5huGLZGSGXU9V9YTxU9vwZs73eUbkxON0GU/edit?usp=sharing)

```
Last login: Tue Jul  2 15:33:31 on ttys000
/var/folders/jv/9_sy0bn10mbdft1bk9t14qz40000gn/T/Cleanup\ At\ Startup/ieca_first_col-394486416.142.py.command ; exit;
Samuel-Finegolds-MacBook-Pro:~ samuelfinegold$ /var/folders/jv/9_sy0bn10mbdft1bk9t14qz40000gn/T/Cleanup\ At\ Startup/ieca_first_col-394486416.142.py.command ; exit;



 range 4
split area nmdeg
 CEP
['Lannister G. Cersei M.A.T.']
({'additionaltext': '',
  'bio': '',
  'category': ' CEP',
  'certifications': [],
  'company': '',
  'counselingoptions': [],
  'counselingtype': [],
  'datasource': {'additionaltext': '',
                 'linktext': '',
                 'linkurl': '',
                 'logourl': ''},
  'degrees': ['M.A.T.'],
  'description': '',
  'email': {'emailtype': [], 'value': 'cersei@got.com'},
  'facebook': '',
  'languages': 'english',
  'linkedin': '',
  'linktext': '',
  'linkurl': '',
  'location': {'address': '',
               'city': '',
               'country': 'united states',
               'geo': {'lat': '', 'lng': ''},
               'loc_name': '',
               'locationtype': '',
               'state': '',
               'zip': ''},
  'logourl': '',
  'name': {'first_name': u'Lannister',
           'last_name': u'Cersei',
           'middle_name': u'G.',
           'title': u''},
  'phone': {'phonetype': [], 'value': '1112223333'},
  'photo': '',
  'price': {'costrange': [], 'costtype': []},
  'twitter': '',
  'website': ''},)
({'additionaltext': '',
  'bio': '',
  'category': [],
  'certifications': [],
  'company': '',
  'counselingoptions': [],
  'counselingtype': [],
  'datasource': {'additionaltext': '',
                 'linktext': '',
                 'linkurl': '',
                 'logourl': ''},
  'degrees': ['Ed.M.'],
  'description': '',
  'email': {'emailtype': [], 'value': ''},
  'facebook': '',
  'languages': 'english',
  'linkedin': '',
  'linktext': '',
  'linkurl': '',
  'location': {'address': '',
               'city': '',
               'country': 'united states',
               'geo': {'lat': '', 'lng': ''},
               'loc_name': '',
               'locationtype': '',
               'state': '',
               'zip': ''},
  'logourl': '',
  'name': {'first_name': u'Argle',
           'last_name': u'Bargle',
           'middle_name': u'D.',
           'title': u''},
  'phone': {'phonetype': [], 'value': ''},
  'photo': '',
  'price': {'costrange': [], 'costtype': []},
  'twitter': '',
  'website': ''},)
({'additionaltext': '',
  'bio': '',
  'category': [],
  'certifications': [],
  'company': '',
  'counselingoptions': [],
  'counselingtype': [],
  'datasource': {'additionaltext': '',
                 'linktext': '',
                 'linkurl': '',
                 'logourl': ''},
  'degrees': ['Ed.M.'],
  'description': '',
  'email': {'emailtype': [], 'value': 'dman123@gmail.com'},
  'facebook': '',
  'languages': 'english',
  'linkedin': '',
  'linktext': '',
  'linkurl': '',
  'location': {'address': '',
               'city': '',
               'country': 'united states',
               'geo': {'lat': '', 'lng': ''},
               'loc_name': '',
               'locationtype': '',
               'state': '',
               'zip': ''},
  'logourl': '',
  'name': {'first_name': u'Sam',
           'last_name': u'Man',
           'middle_name': u'D.',
           'title': u''},
  'phone': {'phonetype': [], 'value': '0000001111'},
  'photo': '',
  'price': {'costrange': [], 'costtype': []},
  'twitter': '',
  'website': ''},)
({'additionaltext': '',
  'bio': '',
  'category': [],
  'certifications': [],
  'company': '',
  'counselingoptions': [],
  'counselingtype': [],
  'datasource': {'additionaltext': '',
                 'linktext': '',
                 'linkurl': '',
                 'logourl': ''},
  'degrees': ['M.S.'],
  'description': '',
  'email': {'emailtype': [], 'value': ''},
  'facebook': '',
  'languages': 'english',
  'linkedin': '',
  'linktext': '',
  'linkurl': '',
  'location': {'address': '',
               'city': '',
               'country': 'united states',
               'geo': {'lat': '', 'lng': ''},
               'loc_name': '',
               'locationtype': '',
               'state': '',
               'zip': ''},
  'logourl': '',
  'name': {'first_name': u'D',
           'last_name': u'Bamf',
           'middle_name': u'G',
           'title': u''},
  'phone': {'phonetype': [], 'value': ''},
  'photo': '',
  'price': {'costrange': [], 'costtype': []},
  'twitter': '',
  'website': ''},)
logout

[Process completed]
```

Comment: Thank you for that edit! Couldn't figure out what was causing the tab issue.

Comment: `name = HumanName(name)`. `name` is not defined before this line.

Comment: See discussion on answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a local variable `name` here:

```
name = HumanName(name)
```

You do set `name` before that point, but only if certain conditions match. When those conditions do not match, `name` is never assigned to and the exception is thrown.

For example, in the first `if` branch, the loop is:

```
for word in split_name_deg:
    for deg in degrees:
        if deg == word:
            degrees_list.append(split_name_deg.pop())
            name = ' '.join(split_name_deg)
```

If `deg == word` never matches, then `name` is never set either.

Your function also doesn't *return* anything, so the line `a = parse_ieca_gc(s)` will only ever assign `None` to `a`. You need to use the `return` keyword to set a return value for your function.

Last but not least, you only pass the first row from your CSV file to the function, and that first row has *no* website associated with it:

```
Diane Grant Albrecht M.S.
```

Comment: Name is assigned either way, no? Either there is a comma or there isn't. If there is, name is assigned. If there isn't name is still assigned.

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry, I see: there's no 'M.S.' in degrees so deg != word

Comment: Also, do you know why it's not returning a website?

Comment: I am having a hard time following what your code is supposed to do; your indentation seems to be off. Where is it supposed to return a website? Note that if you have more questions, perhaps you should create another post.

Comment: @goldisfine: How do you know it is not picking up website? All you do is assign it to a local variable.

Comment: Indentation corrected. The file is tab-delimited and has a column 'website' which, when accessed, should return a website. Can't ask more qs today.

Comment: Sorry, I'm running a loop on my computer in my code that iterates over all of the rows in the example and it doesn't return a website entry.

Comment: No you don't. Your loop appends the rows to `myjson`, but then you only use `myjson[0]` later on. You don't pass each row from the CSV to your function, you only call the function for the first row.

Comment: Sorry to waste your time, it was 'website ', not 'website' (space at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I thought leaving a comment, but I guess that should actually qualify as an answer. You seem to like programming (or at least be serious about it), so please take my answer positively: not as another piece of criticisms but as an advice how to avoid similar errors/problems in the future.

This are just a few points that I came up with after reading your code:

## 1) Add entry points

Code is messy which makes it difficult to find and follow the main line of your thinking (the program logic). Since you are not just prototyping or experimenting, but writing a functioning program you should really add an entry point. In python one first defines his module with all entries and elements (mainly imports, constants and functions), and only then sets the entry point with the section: `if __name__ == '__main__':` at the bottom of the module.

## 2) Break code into many functions

The program is not that big, but because you are trying to do too much (very quick-n-dirty) and using just few lines it becomes dangerous. Your code growth organically very fast and exposing it errors like this. Please take your time and learn how to break your code into functions, which are the basic building blocks for each module. Try to define many small self-consistent functions in your module and call them from the main part of the program. If you manage to give them proper names - your code will be very readable, especially starting with **`__main__`** part.

Treat each function as a small program (divide and conquer). Keep each function small in number of lines (<= 20) and compact in number of arguments (<= 5-7). It has many advantages:

- you can test the code of each function individually and be sure that it is working by using calls form `__main__`, doctests or unittests. Like this, you will always have full control of your program even before/without applying sophisticated debugging techniques
- each function is a closure and declared variables a bounded to a local scope. This helps to avoid complications with global variables that may lead to "side-effects".
- functions can be imported by other modules. Like this you have a better organization of the code and greater re-usability.

## 3) Never write too much code without running it

Progressing slowly allows to keep constant overview of your idea while writing the program. Even if the code will end up uglier than you would wish it to be, any incremental change to your code should be traceable (you kind-of know/observe how much code is added with each step). You can also start using version control even locally (just for yourself), that will allow you to progress slowly by keeping your commits atomic and self-contained.

## 4) Print and die

If you still feel like you give to far or written too much code w/o running it, your end up in a situation similar to yours now. Another trick could be just to put `exit()` call in the middle or before of the newly written code that breaks (by checking line number of the exception info). In most cases,  trying to print out variables and check if their values are similar to expected helps to find the problem. Otherwise just comment a section of you program in order to make a few steps back (cutting it until it gets that small that whatever is "on" - works)

## 5) Cyclic complexity

Avoid too many nested loops and conditional constructions. Try to do not more than 2-3 nested blocks per function. It is important matter. Use tools like pylint and PEP8 to check the quality of your code. You will be surprised how many complains those tools are capable to find about the code that looks decent. E.g. there is a lot of motivation for having 80 chars limit per line of your code. That really does prevent writing too much hanging and nested code. Ideally code is always compact: each function is not too wide, and not too tall.

## 6) Avoid

Finally, try to avoid

- reassigning variables to itself, especially if your are changing the type in addition: `name = HumanName(name)`
- defining "hanging" variables inside nested blocks and expressions which may or may not take place
- dependency on global variables (exactly by defining functions!) and too much cross dependencies. Unless you program a recursive algorithm, you should be totally fine with top down approach. Dependencies on badly tested, uncertain outcomes.
- respect indent - always replace tabs! you would not make it far in python if you don't do it (set ts=4 | set sw=4 | set et)

If you write a line of code that takes you too long to think afterwards, consider correcting it. If you write a function that you later don't understand, consider throwing it away. If you do everything right and
you get an error that you don't understand, consider going to sleep.

PS

Don't forget to smoke the famous

```
>>> import this
```

Hope some of the points are useful.

GL!

Comment: Thanks Yauhen! Not criticism at all, but very constructive. Will be sure to break code into functions given how easily I could then reuse + how it gives me more control. Like the exit() trick.  And I will try to avoid too much nesting and lazy variable naming. Still working on understanding entry points, but sure it will come. Thx again!